# Why trees in the way

Tags: particles

I have weight paint and made the vertex. I have made 3 tress group. In the particles tab with the tree group selected. The problem is the weight paint i have made i dont need the trees in the way. I have click the side arrow negative the effect. Yet the result as u seen below the trees are in the way. My weight paint vertex is straight like a road but the trees coming the way. Why the trees not arrange in a row so that i can see a straight road.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Weight painting only controls particle probability, not direction, it won't make them line up in a row. If you want less trees widen the road

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You mean i have to make the road widen with painting the red color more.

Comment: @atek I have noticed that your 3 trees are combined into one mesh.
I would recommend making this 3 seperate objects and then group them together.
Make sure the origin of each tree is at the bottom center of each tree.
Then choose group under the particle render tab.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix for the given file

- Made the adjustments @Delagone suggested:

  - Separated the tree object
  - Set the object origins for each tree object root.
  - Made sure the three tree objects are in one group
  - Choose the group instead of the object in the "Render" tab.
- In the "Emission" tab

  - Emit from: "Verts"
  - Unchecked "Random"

[image]

## Distributing particle system with weight painting

### Particle system source mesh

The mesh resolution of the plane is very low.

The weight painting is saved in the vertices of the mesh. The more control you want over the weight painting and therefore the distribution of the particle system, the more resolution the mesh needs.

### Emission of the particle system

[image]

The emission from setting tells the particle system where it should emit the particles. In the case of a plane with weight paint it should be set to "Verts" or "Faces".

### Weight painting

You want a road with trees on both sides.

Then you need to weight paint to lines of both sides of the street where the trees should be. 
The weight painting tells the particle system where it should put the trees.

The weight paint tells the particle system the probability

Example weight paints for road straight and with side street:

[image] [image]

Comment: I have attach my file and the problem is with the reference i have made 2 road its not align inside but a new problem is the particles are outside the mesh.