# Problem: Particle System Objects Collide With Mesh on the Scene

Tags: particles, system

I have used particle system to randomly put trees on the grass field shown on the screen. Then I made a road mesh which I put over that grass field without joining road and field into one object. The question is can I somehow make trees not bump right out of road without turning off the particle system and placing trees by myself. 
[image]

Comment: Use weight paint to determine which areas of the landscape should not have particles. Then in the particle settings look for the vertex group section and set the vertex group (created automatically by the texture paint) to control the density 
 of the paricles. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96350/how-do-i-add-spikes-my-characters-arms/96415#96415

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90313/why-trees-in-the-way